# Cyrillic characters in Sublime Text 3 with Terminus font

Tags: windows, fonts, character-encoding, sublime-text-3

I have an issue with displaying Cyrillic characters in Sublime Text 3 when I choose my favorite Terminus font: all they looks like unfilled rectangles. In other text editors I have a "character set" option in the font settings panel where I can select "Cyrillic" and everything will be fine. Unfortunately I didn't find similar option in the Sublime Text. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [TTF version](http://files.ax86.net/terminus-ttf/#download) of Terminus.

Then, in Sublime's Preferences file:

```
"font_face": "Terminus (TTF)",
"font_size": 15
```

See the website for best supported sizes.

Comment: Yeap, this works, but unfortunately TTF version of this font looks much worse than bitmap version. It looses all its charm.

Comment: @Menzoda yeah, I'm sad about it.

Comment: Anyway thanks for help. I mark this answer as accepted because currently it is the only working solution.